# GA4 - Item Scoped Custom Dimensions Via GTM GA4 Event Tag?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Been preparing for the Universal Analytics migration to GA4 and have been having issues with item scoped parameters.

Currently I have some parameters which are meant to be item scoped dimensions. All my other parameters are being pushed through GTM under the 'Google Analytics: GA4 Event' Tag Type. There seems to be a spot for 'Event Parameters' and 'User Properties', however I can't seem to find dedicated a spot for 'Item Parameters

[image: Screenshot of GA4 Event Tag Type]'.

Does anyone know if GTM 'GA4 Event' Tag Type is just currently behind on native support for GA4 item scoped parameters? Or is the only way through a DataLayer push?

I've tried placing my item parameters under the 'Event Parameters' section, but when I navigate to GA4 to create custom definitions it doesn't allow me to pick those parameters as item scoped...

I'm aware of pushing the items through a separate dataLayer push, but due to our current configuration. All other parameters (Event/User) scoped definitions are being pushed directly through the 'GA4 Event' Tag Type.

Answer (score 0):

As the document mentioned here [document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#add_or_remove_an_item_from_a_shopping_cart)

You can just set it in event parameter like this.

[image]

The expected value in the `Variable` like:

```
[
    {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
      affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
      coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
      discount: 2.22,
      index: 0,
      item_brand: "Google",
      item_category: "Apparel",
      item_category2: "Adult",
      item_category3: "Shirts",
      item_category4: "Crew",
      item_category5: "Short sleeve",
      item_list_id: "related_products",
      item_list_name: "Related Products",
      item_variant: "green",
      location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
      price: 9.99,
      quantity: 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Darrell, are item scoped dimensions only limited ecommerce interactions? Can they be used for custom events?